# Dividing Large dataset into equal lists in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 2 SQL databases, 1 being a list of agents and the other being clients.

i would like to randomly split the client database amongst the number of agents i have. ie
if i have 10 agents and 50 000 clients, each agent must get an equal unique list based on the number of clients available. (10 lists of 5000 totally random selected clients without any duplication)

i am still very much a novice at at SQL and have tried to assign ID numbers to the client list based on the amount of agents i have and then joining them up like that. I would like to try something a bit more random than just going 1,2,3, and joining them up like tht

i would like to do it either in SQL or Excel.

Please Help...

Comment: we're here to solve code problems, which means that you need some code to ask support for: we can't suggest you solutions or provide original code!

Comment: use a window function and post where you get stuck

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) % 10 as AgentIndex
FROM Clients
```

The `AgentIndex` will be in the range of 0 to 9. Each agent will have 5000 clients associated with it.

Comment: "…in the range of 0 to **9**"? Or is that a language issue? I mean, I don't know whether "to" is supposed to mean "until, but not including" here (English isn't my native language).

Comment: Was an error, sorry for the confusion. The correct interval is [0, 9].

Comment: Oh, it's all right, my initial guess was correct then, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: And the idea itself is nice, by the way (don't know why I forgot to vote this the first time).

Answer (score 0):

Using T-SQL you could use NEWID() to generate a random value for each row. You can then order your recordset by this value and use SELECT TOP to get the first 5000 elements, and so on.

```
SELECT *, NEWID() AS RandomNumber INTO #MyTempTable FROM MyTable

SELECT TOP 5000 * FROM #MyTempTable ORDER BY RandomNumber
```